# How to add more space to the elementary OS partition from the Windows one?

Tags: release-juno, dual-boot, hardware, microsoft-windows

I dual boot elementary with Windows 10 on my laptop. When I was installing the OS, it let me choose how much space to get off of the Windows 10 drive but now that space is running low and I want to add more to it.

I can't fully let go of the Windows partitiont yet because I still have softwae that I require to use there that don't work in WINE.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already know what you have to do. You need to resize your partitions. You can do it from any end, either Windows or elementary OS. Please read these guides thoroughly, I believe you will have a clear idea.
1. [Add more disk space for linux from windows in a dual bootable machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871825/add-more-disk-space-for-linux-from-windows-in-a-dual-bootable-machine)
2. [Give more Hard disk space to Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727112/give-more-hard-disk-space-to-ubuntu?noredirect=1&lq=1)
3. [Increasing the Size of an Ubuntu Partition when Dual Booted with Windows 8](http://joejanuszk.com/blog/increasing-ubuntu-partition-size-dual-boot-windows/)

P.S: Ignore the OS versions.